# paypal sandbox testing not working

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I'm doing Paypal sandbox testing but I'm not able to do that.
I'm using dummy creditcard numbers, but everytime I get an error.
I've attached the image of the error.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc-facilitator@ratufa.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="PHPGang Payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="credits" value="510">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/uploads/gang.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/paypal/cancel.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/paypal/success.php">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

[image]

[image]
I have tried a lot of dummy credit cards numbers from so many sites. But none worked for me. 
I get this error every time or one more error like

> this credit card is linked with some other email address.

I changed email address too.
I'm using a Paypal business acount like abc-facilitator@gmail.com

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Did you set up sandbox test accounts?

Comment: yes i did all this stuff.

Comment: Have bug like your. PayPal sandbox works not stable.
Yesterday i cant saw my apps. Today all works fine

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a standard PayPal payment button and not a subscription for sandbox testing. This will show you how the plugin works.